# Why is readxl so much faster than xlsx package?

Tags: r, excel

We used the two packages [xlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) and [readxl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) and now it seems, readxl is much faster. Why? As long-term stability is important to us, I would then always use the readxl package.

Reproducible example:

```
path <- "C:/Temp/"
name <- "myexcel.xlsx"
filename <- paste0(path, name)
dim <- c(14000, 30)
rands <- matrix(data = runif(n = dim[1]*dim[2], min = 0, max = 1), nrow = dim[1], ncol = dim[2])
df <- as.data.frame(rands)
writexl::write_xlsx(x = df, path = filename, col_names = TRUE)
# xlsx::write.xlsx(x = df, file = filename, sheetName = "Sheet1")
# Does not give a result

mytable <- readxl::read_excel(path = filename, sheet = "Sheet1")
# mytable2 <- xlsx::read.xlsx(file = filename, sheetName = "Sheet1")
# Does not give a result
```

Comment: Presumably because ‘readxl’ is implemented using a native library, whereas ‘xlsx’ uses Java, which incurs a non-trivial overhead to marshal data between the Java memory model and the C memory model (and then the R memory model). — Anyway, why do you care? Just use the modern, fast library.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OK, I just was not sure because xlsx package is still updated / improved. I thought, there is a reason for two packages...